# issues after removing window.web3

Tags: web3js, web3-providers

I am taking a smart contract course on udemy which belongs to 2017.Many web3 versions have come since then which is making me confused to implement what i am learning in newer versions.
When i want to create an instance of web3 on my project(web3.js) and use it in another script(app.js) and print it on console, I am facing an empty array instead of array including my meta mask address.

web3.js

```
import Web3 from "web3";

const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);

export default web3;
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import web3 from "./web3";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log);
    console.log(web3.version);
    console.log("Salam agha sina!");
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
  
  

export default App;
```

Comment: Well start with debugging ```window.web3.currentProvider```. If this is empty then you do not have injected ```web3``` variable. Usually providers like MetaMask or Trust Wallet browser have built-in ```web3``` variable and ```web3.currentProvider``` is an object.

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused because you haven't **enabled** the web3 object through your browser and hence, you get an empty array from accounts. You can try using this code (before retrieving the accounts):

```
    if (window.ethereum) {
        web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        await window.ethereum.enable();
    } else if (window.web3) {
        web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        window.alert('Non-Ethereum browser detected. Please install MetaMask plugin');
    };
```

On the other hand, your browser should have a web3 plugin installed (e.g.: Metamask).

Answer (score 1):

> On the other hand, your browser should have a web3 plugin installed (e.g.: Metamask).

MetaMask removed Web3 injection a couple days ago.
https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/pull/9156

Comment: So, What is the replacement bro?

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing this incase anyone ends up here for the same reason I did.

I followed the new Metamask provider guide but was still getting the error:

"We noticed that the current website tried to use the removed window.web3 API. If the site appears to be broken, please click here for more information."

After some time debugging, it turned out I simply needed to uninstall Metamask from my browser and reinstall it using the seed phrase.

After doing this I no longer got the error. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you. I spent a day searching for where I forget to remove window.web3 but my code was correct and only after reinstalling Metamask this notice has gone